# Does Titanium Backup break 'Sleep As Android?

Tags: titanium-backup, compatibility

Whenever I hit the button to start tracking my sleeping, [Sleep As Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep&hl=en) warns `'Titanium Backup' may break sleep tracking!`

I was wondering under what circumstances does this happen and how to prevent it? It's kind of really important to have an alarm.

I found a little information on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sleep-as-an-droid/CG6S4SRo5SY).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be because you can schedule backups within Titanium Backup, and when backing up the 'Sleep As Android' app Titanium Backup may/will kill the application in order to perform the backup. By doing this the app will no longer track you sleep or wake you up at the required time. I don't think that simply having Titanium Backup installed will break the sleep tracking.

Comment: +1: TiBu will definitely need to stop the app in order to back it up (I'm not sure if it also "restarts" it afterwards – there are at least two different ways to stop an app). The Schedules are exactly what I think stands behind the warning. I fully agree just having TiBu installed is a danger here, not even schedules in general (Sleep As Android can hardly tell what exactly is scheduled – could as well be a simple "Backup SMS to XML" ;) Note the word ***may*** in the warning: It might as well not :)